# Generate random vertex of regular polygon

Tags: polygon, vertices

I need help with programming random vertices of regular polygon. I want to get a function, where for n regular polygon get vertices of random coordinates. I tried like this but I have to have coordinates of poly. Any help?

```
import random

def polygon_random_points (poly, num_points):
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds
    points = []
    while len(points) < num_points:
        random_point = Point([random.uniform(min_x, max_x), random.uniform(min_y, max_y)])
        if (random_point.within(poly)):
            points.append(random_point)
    return points
```